# How to have different widgets for different versions of Android?

Tags: android, widget, gesture

I have one Application, and I want to add a widget.

I've been digging through the documents, and it looks like only Android 3.0+ supports gesture-based views in a widget.  For example, I can scroll my email on the gmail widget on 4.03 as a listView, and I have also seen a GridView widget (on 4.03).

So, these types of widgets cannot be used in 2.2 and 2.3

Is there any way I can have my application provide one gesturable widget for 4.0 and if the user has 2.3, it will load a different widget?

I have no problem writing both widgets, which both work-- I just want users on 2.2 to use my 2.2 widget and users on 3.0+ to use my 3.0+ widget.

Is this possible from one application?

Thanks!

Comment: you can check the android version at build time and determine which version is running on the device and accordingly which widget should your app use.

Comment: yeah, I was secretly hoping this wasn't the only way, but that'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android has facilities for resources and code to switch on the version. no, there's nothing high level like adding a version number to your widget's XML.

for layouts, and other resources, you can name the resource folders as,

```
res/values-v11
res/layout-v11
```

etc. android will pull the best-match resource at runtime. in the code, you can check the SDK version,

```
if (Build.VERSION < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // handle android 2 here
}
```

Comment: If android will pull the best-match resource at runtime, why do I have to check the code?  To make sure the presenter logic is with the correct view?

Comment: exactly. if the widgets are significantly different, the layout may have different elements, and the handler logic may be different. it depends on your code though. you may be able to get away with just having two different layouts.

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking about trying to get the `id` values to match across the layouts, and I can avoid this. Thanks anyways!